# VueJS - Auto Fill Selected Dropdown List Relate Field

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I have `Related data` between `Province` and `District`, `Province hasMany District`.

I have `Object` something like this.

```
{
        "id": 1,
        "name_eng": "Banteay Meanchey",
        "name_kh": "បន្ទាយមានជ័យ",
        "district": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "name_eng": "Mongkol Borei",
                "name_kh": "មង្គលបុរី",
                "province": 1
            }
        ]
    },
```

[image]

I have form like above image, All i want is when select `Province` the field `District` will `Auto Filled` to related relationship.

Between i use `Vuetify` `v-autocomplete`

```
    <label
        >Pls Select Province/District</label
    >
    <v-autocomplete
        :items="provinces"
        item-id="id"
        item-text="name_kh"
        label="Pls Select Province"
        solo
        v-model="form.province"
        return-object
    >
    </v-autocomplete>
    <v-autocomplete
        :items="provinces"
        item-id="id"
        item-text="name_kh"
        label="Pls Select District"
        solo
        v-model="form.province"
        return-object
    >
    </v-autocomplete>
```

**`In script Tag`**

```
<script>
import axios from "axios";

export default {
    data() {
        return {
            menu: false,
            loading: false,
            form: {},
            provinces: [],
        };
    },

    created() {
        this.getProvince();
    },

    computed() {},

    methods: {
        getProvince() {
            axios
                .get(`api/v1/province/`)
                .then((res) => {
                    console.log(res);
                    this.provinces = res.data;
                })
                .catch((err) => {
                    console.log(err.response);
                });
        },
    },
};
</script>
```

I'll appreciate of all ur help :) Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On district dropdown, you can be looping by selected province like below

```
<v-autocomplete
        :items="getDistrictsByProvince(form.province)"
        item-id="id"
        item-text="name_kh"
        label="Pls Select District"
        solo
        v-model="form.province"
        return-object
    >
</v-autocomplete>
```

In script Tag under method:

```
getDistrictsByProvince(province) {
  if(province){
    return this.provinces.find(item => item.id === province.id).district
  } else {
    return []
  }

}
```

Comment: after correct some part from ur code, i make it working. Can u explain me detail ur code??

Comment: which part needs to be clarified?

Comment: `return this.provinces.find(item => item.id === province.id).district` this line bro :)

Comment: This line simply find by provinces id object after getting the targeted object  .district can return a list of the district from province object